# How to average spatial points data over spatial grid boxes in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a set of data points that have coordinates and one value associated with them. I would like to be able to place the data points into grid boxes and average all the points that fall into each grid box.

Here is the code I managed to create that makes what I want. I wonder if there is a more elegant and more efficient way to do that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# ***********************************************
# *** Get mean data in 1°x1° lat×lon grid box ***
    
# Dataset
lats =  np.array((40.1, 42.1, 40.7, 43.1, 41.0, 42.7, 40.7, 43.1, 41.2, 42.7, 40.5, 43.1, 40.2))
lons =  np.array(( 1.2,  2.6,  3.1,  1.7,  2.1,  1.9,  3.4,  2.7,  3.4,  1.3,  2.1,  2.9,  3.7))
temps = np.array((28.3, 25.1, 24.3, 27.4, 26.3, 21.3, 25.0, 21.9, 22.8, 21.7, 23.8, 21.5, 20.1))

# Initialization
latbins = np.arange(-90, 90.1, 1)
lonbins = np.arange(0, 360.1, 1)
sum_temp = np.zeros((latbins.size-1, lonbins.size-1))
occ_temp = np.zeros((latbins.size-1, lonbins.size-1))

# Sum and count data in grid box 
for i, temp in enumerate(temps):
    # Get index of grid box where to add the data
    i_latbin = 0
    while lats[i] > latbins[i_latbin]:
        i_latbin += 1
    i_lonbin = 0
    while lons[i] > lonbins[i_lonbin]:
        i_lonbin += 1  
    
    # Add the data
    sum_temp[i_latbin-1, i_lonbin-1] += temp
    occ_temp[i_latbin-1, i_lonbin-1] += 1

# Compute mean
FILL_VALUE = -9999.
mean_temp = np.ones((latbins.size-1, lonbins.size-1))*FILL_VALUE
mean_temp[occ_temp != 0] = sum_temp[occ_temp != 0]/occ_temp[occ_temp != 0]
mean_temp = np.ma.masked_where(mean_temp==FILL_VALUE, mean_temp)


# ****************
# *** Plot map ***

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 10))

# Plot mean data
ax = plt.subplot(211)
ax.set_facecolor('0.8')
plt.pcolormesh(lonbins, latbins, mean_temp, cmap=cm.RdBu_r)
plt.colorbar(label='Temperature (°C)')
plt.xlim(1, 4)
plt.ylim(40, 44)
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')

# Plot number of observations
ax = plt.subplot(212)
plt.pcolormesh(lonbins, latbins, occ_temp)
plt.colorbar(label='Number of observations')
plt.xlim(1, 4)
plt.ylim(40, 44)
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you could use the built in numpy function histogram2d for that. There is just one caveat the bins aren't `>` but `>=`. So the picture would look a little bit different.

```
# Initialization
latbins = np.arange(-90, 90.1, 1)
lonbins = np.arange(0, 360.1, 1)
sum_temp = np.zeros((latbins.size-1, lonbins.size-1))
occ_temp = np.zeros((latbins.size-1, lonbins.size-1))

occ_temp, lonbins, latbins = np.histogram2d(lons, lats, bins = [lonbins, latbins])
sum_temp, lonbins, latbins = np.histogram2d(lons, lats, bins = [lonbins, latbins], weights=temps)

occ_temp = occ_temp.T
sum_temp = sum_temp.T

# Compute mean
FILL_VALUE = -9999.
mean_temp = np.ones((latbins.size-1, lonbins.size-1))*FILL_VALUE
mean_temp[occ_temp != 0] = sum_temp[occ_temp != 0]/occ_temp[occ_temp != 0]
mean_temp = np.ma.masked_where(mean_temp==FILL_VALUE, mean_temp)


# ****************
# *** Plot map ***
X, Y = np.meshgrid(lonbins, latbins)
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 10))

# Plot mean data
ax = plt.subplot(211)
ax.set_facecolor('0.8')
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, mean_temp, cmap=cm.RdBu_r)
plt.colorbar(label='Temperature (°C)')
plt.xlim(1, 4)
plt.ylim(40, 44)
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')

# Plot number of observations

ax = plt.subplot(212)
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, occ_temp)
plt.colorbar(label='Number of observations')
plt.xlim(1, 4)
plt.ylim(40, 44)
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Using `np.histogram2d` is a great idea! What's the main advantage for using `X, Y = np.meshgrid(lonbins, latbins)` instead of `lonbins, latbins` in `plt.pcolormesh()`?

Comment: Nothing really. When I was trying to solve it, I was adapting an example from the documentation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html